Lombok @Getter having onMethod_ for class doesnt work
I am having a class where I need, say, @CustomAnnotation for each single getter in a class,
public class Pojo{

    private String name;
    private int age;

    @CustomAnnotation
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @CustomAnnotation
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
}

I am thinking to place a @Getter on the class level, and expecting lombok to generate the getters with annotations
@Getter(onMethod_ = @CustomAnnotation)
public class Pojo{
    private String name;
    private int age;
}

If I place the @Getter on the field level, problem solved, but obviously not ideal.
There has been a ticket in lombok's issues
https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1653, seems that has been implemented, but I am still getting nothing
lombok version 1.18.34
java version 21

Please show a [mcve] that shows that the annotation is not present. I cannot reproduce the issue. I can successfully retrieve the annotation with getAnnotation on the corresponding Method.

@Getter(onMethod_ = @Deprecated)
public class Pojo{
private String name;
private int age;
}
If I place the @Getter on field level, issue solved, but obviously not ideal
